# Passing inputs to multiple commands in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to auto set the user password. For example I want to set the password for a no-root user to a value stored somewhere else in the script.

I am doing the following:

```
echo $input | passwd $user
```

However it fails since there is a prompt for Retype the new password.

I tried:

```
echo $input | passwd $user
echo $input | Retype New Password:
```

with no luck. It says password change aborted. How do I accomplish this? Does calling out for retyping a new password invokes another shell process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just insert a newline:

```
echo $input$'\n'$input | passwd $user
```

Or use `echo -e`

```
echo -e "$input\n$input" | passwd $user
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Grimm. Worked like a charm. Can you please explain why new line works?

Comment: `echo`ing text to STDIN of a process is effectively the same as typing, and the enter key produces a `\n`.

Comment: @brotherofmysister You should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: sorry was offline for an hour :) Thanks @ Ben Grimm